# How to track CTR (click-through rate) with Google Analytics?

Tags: google-analytics

I implemented Google Analytics with Google Tag Manager.

Let's say that I have a landing page, on which there is a call-to-action link/button. How do I track the CTR (click-through rate) of this landing page with Google Analytics?

Although I found a [YouTube video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=wZDoPxWPJAs) briefly illustrating how to do that, I'm not seeing the table shown in the video and instead I'm seeing a message titled "**This report requires Search Console integration to be enabled.**"

== Edit ==
I already had my "CTA click" event tracking set up through Google Tag Manager. I just don't know how to convert those event records into CTR statistics.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Reading through your post and titico's answer, what you need to do to derive the Click Through Rate of your Landing Page is divide the no. of unique events that happened by the no. of unique visits.

I believe Google Analytics has Custom Metrics (not Dimensions) which you can define as this number and track.

Here the basic assumption is that you want to track the efficacy of your landing page copy and multiple impressions of the same copy wont impact the CTR. However, if you feel that each time the same user is arriving on the same landing page, you need to check the CTR, then your Custom Metric would be defined by total events divided by total visits to the landing page.

There is one more method of tracking this, using Custom Segments!

In Custom Segments you can define the order in which things happened in a particular session. So in this case, it would be - All the sessions where the user arrived on your landing page, and then the event occurred.

Hope this helps!

Comment: It seems to me that your method is valid. But I'm unable to implement it with only these instructions.

Comment: You need more help on Segments or Metrics? Another way to do this would be via Excel.

A last method for this would also be to define that event as a conversion and look at the conversion rate.

Comment: Thank you. I decided to code my own CTR tracker. I guess such a data in GA won't be real-time anyway.

Answer (score 0):

You should be looking at “Google Analytics event tracking with Google Tag Manager”, there are plenty of tutorials online. However, Follow [these detailed instructions](https://support.google.com/analytics/answer/6164470?hl=en) on how to do that.

Event tracking means that whenever an user clicks on a link that will generate an link/button click event and if you have set it up correctly each click will be counted.

You don’t need to set up Search Console or Google webmaster tools to do that. Basically, create the tag and configure it.

Comment: Sorry for not mentioning it in advance, but I already had my event tracking set up through Google Tag Manager. When visitors click on my CTA link/button, Google Analytics does show the event records. Now I just don't know how to convert those event records into CTR statistics.